# What does "Unable to instatiate activity ComponentInfo" stands for?

Tags: android, gps, components, info

I am trying to develop Android app, something with GPS, and using Google Maps API v2. This error ([bigger picture in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbAcT.png)) is showing up and app crashes immidiately after run.

[image: link to image]

And here's the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bajo.moj.gpsreminder" >
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- dobivanje douštenja za MAPE -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.bajo.moj.gpsreminder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.bajo.moj.gpsreminder.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


    <!-- doupuštenje za Internet, vanjsku pohranu i ostalo-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gfs.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <!-- nije potrebno za Google Maps API v2, ali je recommended -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <!-- OpenGL verzija 2.0 za renderanje screen-a -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- kljuc od Google-a -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCV9Plzy-RcaJ30cnXw_jRgXjg5czLIS9A"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

//Also, I am using 2 Java Activities like below:  -> I am not.
[image]

- MainActivity code: [MainActivity](http://pastebin.com/xtmffYSv)
- LocationProvider code: [LocationProvider](http://pastebin.com/TBHEagLA)
- [Error that's showing](http://pastebin.com/a46t3uCA) and why app still crashes...

Answer (score 0):

> I am using 2 Java Activities like below

Did you say you have two activities? If so, you haven't declared one of them in the manifest file.

Comment: I did added second Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/3kDMa1e.png)
But it's underlined red and now I cannot run app on my device.

Comment: I see. But your manifest file doesn't show that though. There's only the MainActivity declared in that file or at least in the picture.

Comment: Can you please take a snapshot of the LocationProvider class' code?

Comment: LocationProvider is not an activity. That's why you get that red line under its name in your manifest.

Comment: So I should delete  <activity
        android:name=".LocationProvider" >
    </activity>
But why do I get error posted in first post?

Comment: You should definitely delete <activity android:name=".LocationProvider" > </activity>. As for your original error, could you please post the code of your main activity too?

Comment: OK, I deleted code from AndroidManifest.xml. [Here is MainActivity.](http://pastebin.com/xtmffYSv) Also, [here](http://pastebin.com/PRSvS7nn) is complete error that is showing up all the time.

Comment: So, do you have a fragment tag in your activity_main.xml file with the id: map? (R.id.map)

Comment: I do, but I get [this error](http://i.imgur.com/GhhJ3pU.png), not sure if that's relevant...

Comment: Hmm .. base on your error:
at com.bajo.moj.gpsreminder.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:67) it seems like it can't find that fragment.

Comment: Here is also [Text view](http://i.imgur.com/cYp3a2F.png). I'm not sure how to solve this problem, as I think that I added fragment with id: map...

Comment: So, you should move android:text="@string/hello_world" inside the textView tag.

Comment: OK, I [did](http://i.imgur.com/9snP1Lo.png). Do you maybe have some other solution why the app still crashes?

Comment: It's OK. Thank you for trying! If anyone else know what's may be the problem and how to solve it, please help. Here's the [latest error](http://pastebin.com/a46t3uCA). App still crashes when I try to run it.